# Book recommendation for Ashtavakra Gita with original shlokas

Tags: book-recommendation

I want to read [the Ashtavakra Gita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashtavakra_Gita).

I find difficulty in finding the right translations and explanations. Can someone name some widely used translated forms of this book which contain the original shlokas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Advaita Ashrama publishes a lot of books on Sri Ramakrishna, Swami Vivekananda, scriptures etc..Check out [this link](https://shop.advaitaashrama.org/product-category/books/) to browse their books which you can order online.

Books are available in Bengali, English, Hindi, Nepali, Sanskrit, Urdu, English-Bengali.

[Here](https://shop.advaitaashrama.org/product/ashtavakra-samhita/) is the direct link of Ashtavakra Samhita which you want to buy. It contains original Sanskrit Shlokas.

[image]

Comment: The Astavakra Samhita is the only book that Ramakrishna Paramahamsa kept in his room.

Answer (score 3):

I havent read this version, but reading the description, [this](http://bookstore.sriramanamaharshi.org/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=168_169&products_id=6276) should be good. This is from Ramanasharam and based on a book published by Ramakrishna ashram

There is also a free audio download available here http://www.sriramanamaharshi.org/resource_centre/audio/ashtavakra-gita/

You may also search Ramakrishna Mission bookstores